# Remove everything before (including special character) in array

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to remove everything before special characters including this character in `array` ?

For example, `SUBSTR()` function is used in string

```
$a= ('1-160');
echo substr($a,strpos($a,'-')+1);
//output is 160
```

Any function for array like `SUBSTR()`? (least priority to `preg_replace`).

Here array is structured as following example, every index consists `int` value + `hyphen(-)`

```
$a= array('1-160','2-250', '3-380');
```

I need to change removing every values before hyphen and hyphen also

```
$a= array('160','250', '380');
```

Actually my requirement is to sum all values after the `hyphen(-)` in array. If `hyphen(-)` can be removed, it can be done as

```
echo array_sum($a);
//output is 790
```

but, because of the special characters, I am generating output as following way.

```
$total = 0;
foreach($a AS $val){
  $b = explode('-',$val);
  $total += $b[1];
}
echo $total;
//output is 790
```

I am searching short and fast method as possible.

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, `array_sum` would be faster than `explode` and adding value, isn't it ? So I wanna know, can I do `array_sum` in my case.

Comment: preg_grep and array_sum but I doubt it will be faster

Comment: How big is your data set? If it isn't very big, there will most likely not be any noticeable performance differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) with [substr](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php) should work just fine

```
<?php

$a = ['1-160','2-250', '3-380'];
$result = [];

foreach($a as $b) {
    $result[] = substr(strstr($b, '-'), 1); // strstr => get content after needle inclusive needle, substr => remove needle
}

var_dump($result);

var_dump(array_sum($result));
```

https://3v4l.org/2HsAK

Comment: Yeah !! the clean way.

Answer (score 1):

Although you already have the answer, this is for your reference.

```
array_sum(array_map(function ($item) {return explode('-', $item)[1];}, $a));
```